# Why does tf.zeros allow an unknown dimension whereas tf.get_variable doesn't?

Tags: tensorflow

Given some placeholder tensor `x` such that:

`x = tf.placeholder(None, 100)`

I was wondering why:

`h = tf.zeros(shape = (tf.shape(x)[0], 50))`

works but something like:

`h = tf.get_variable("h", shape = (tf.shape(x)[0], 50), initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0.0))`

Gives me a value error:

> ValueError: Shape of a new variable (pred/h) must be fully defined,
>   but instead was (?, 50)

Don't they both initialize some variables, why make it so that `tf.zeros(...)` works with an unknown size, whereas `tf.get_variable(...)` doesn't?

Answer (score 5):

You can have dynamic shapes for run-local tensors(that can be created on the fly when needed for the computation), like zero, ones, random tensors, etc.

But for variables, you can't because they need to be allocated and are conserved between each runs, so they need to have a fixed shape (wich doesn't depend of a run operation).

To get the same result you should use `x.get_shape()[0]` which will return the requested dimention if it is already defined.